# Как правильно перезагрузить Loader?

Tags: android, android-sdk

Есть `EditText`, при изменении его содержимого выполняю рестарт `AsynkTaskLoader-а`, следующим образом:

```
getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(loaderId, bundle, this).forceLoad();
```

Ввожу начало слова, из 3-х букв (например абв), 3-и раза создается Loader, и бывает, что метод onLoadFinished вызывается для результата первых двух букв (аб), а когда завершается работа 3-го лоадера(запрос абв), onLoadFinished не срабатывает. Вот сам лоадер:

```
public class AnswerForQueryLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<AnswerForQuery> {
    private Context mContext;
    private String mQuery;

    public AnswerForQueryLoader(Context context, String query) {
        super(context);
        AppLog.d("AnswerForQueryLoader() = " + query);
        mContext = context;
        mQuery = query;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        super.onStartLoading();
        AppLog.d("AnswerForQueryLoader onStartLoading = " + mQuery);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStopLoading() {
        super.onStopLoading();
        AppLog.d("AnswerForQueryLoader onStopLoading = " + mQuery);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAbandon() {
        super.onAbandon();
        AppLog.d("AnswerForQueryLoader onAbandon = " + mQuery);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReset() {
        super.onReset();
        AppLog.d("AnswerForQueryLoader onReset = " + mQuery);
    }

    @Override
    public AnswerForQuery loadInBackground() {
        AppLog.d("AnswerForQueryLoader loadInBackground start = " + mQuery);
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        DBManager dbManager = DBManager.getInstance(mContext);
        dbManager.open();
        AnswerForQuery answerForQuery = dbManager.getAnswerForQuery(mQuery);
        dbManager.close();

        AppLog.d("AnswerForQueryLoader loadInBackground finish = " + mQuery);
        return answerForQuery;
    }
}
```

Вот сообщения лога:

```
SearchActivity onCreateLoader = а
AnswerForQueryLoader() = а
AnswerForQueryLoader onStartLoading = а
AnswerForQueryLoader loadInBackground start = а
SearchActivity onCreateLoader = аб
AnswerForQueryLoader() = аб
AnswerForQueryLoader loadInBackground start = аб
AnswerForQueryLoader onReset = а
AnswerForQueryLoader onStartLoading = аб
SearchActivity onCreateLoader = абв
AnswerForQueryLoader() = абв
AnswerForQueryLoader loadInBackground start = абв
AnswerForQueryLoader loadInBackground finish = а
AnswerForQueryLoader loadInBackground finish = аб
SearchActivity onLoadFinished = аб
AnswerForQueryLoader onReset = 
AnswerForQueryLoader loadInBackground finish = абв
```

Что нужно поправить, что бы я получал ответ, только от последнего запроса?
Для двух символов всегда возвращает правильный ответ.

**UPD**

Вот как делаю рестарт `Loader`-а по совету `ЮрияСПб`:

```
Loader loader = getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(loaderId);
if(loader != null) {
    loader.cancelLoad();
}

getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(loaderId, bundle, this).forceLoad();
```

Comment: А если попробовать до рестарта лоадера его получить и вызвать на нём `cancelLoad()`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Да действительно так первый раз работает, но после получения результата, и повторного тестирования, не всегда отрабатывает onLoadFinished

Comment: Хм... В доках не очень ясно написано про рестарт... Может, там и не надо после его вызова сразу forceLoad вызывать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб forceLoad нужен, без него не выполняется метод loadInBackground()

Comment: А если restartLoader вызвать в onLoadFinished?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а зачем?

Comment: Ну хз... Вдруг поможет?.. =)